# BackboneJS: Can you change templates of a view on the fly?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Can you change the template of a backbone view by submitting a template option? Code below doesn't seem to work:

```
@company_location= new window.ArtistLocationForm({template: JST["templates/new_company_location"]})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not out-of-the-box.

But all data passed in to the constructor is assigned to this.options on your view instance, so implementing it in the render function should be pretty easy, something like:

```
render: function(){
  var templateFn = this.options.template || this.template;
  this.$el.html(templateFn(this.model.attributes));
  return this;
}
```

should work.